# JSONSerialization ambiguous reference error

Tags: swift3

I have the following code which was converted to Swift 3.2.  The method call to json Object seems correct.

```
open class JsonResponseSerializer : ResponseSerializer {
    open func response(_ data: Data) -> (AnyObject?) {
                return JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions([]), error: nil) as! AnyObject
    }
```

Compiler error:
*Ambiguous reference to member 'jsonObject(with:options:)'*

Answer (score 0):

turns out, removing the "error: nil" param fixed this error.  "Ambiguous reference" is a somewhat, uh, ambiguous error to display...

Comment: You can remove the `options` parameter, too and in Swift 3 the most unspecified type is `Any` (not `AnyObject`). Remove also the parentheses around the return value.